# Using PHP is there a way to detect if there are two uninterrupted occurrences of an element?

Tags: php

This is a difficult question for me to word correctly, but I am trying to dynamically insert an ASIDE [specifically, just a "special thanks" note] between paragraphs. Initially I decided to drop this after the second paragraph by using substr_count(). I am floating this  block, so if all it had to deal with was textual content there was no issue word-wrapping it. However, if it ran adjacent to an image or a PRE or anything else, it got wonky.

Anyway, what I want to do is detect when there is the first occurrence of TWO adjacent paragraphs and insert my aside between those. I.e.:

```
<p> Here is the first paragraph. </p>
<aside> INSERT THIS HERE </aside>
<p> Here is the second paragraph. </p>
```

Thoughts are appreciated.

**Update: the substr_count() I am currently using.**

Because I got voted down for not showing the original code, I'll post it below. I am using Wordpress but this isn't a WP specific question, as I'm taking the_content() as the string, counting the occurrences of P, and inserting the custom field there. This is ultimately not what I want to do, but I want to count two concurrent P's and insert this field between. It may be formatted strangely, as of course when I c/p from my editor stuff was all over the place.

```
$thanks = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'thanks', true);

if (!$thanks) {
  the_content();
}

else {
  $show_after_p = 0;
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
  if(substr_count($content, '<p>') > $show_after_p) {
$contents = explode("</p>", $content);
$p_count = 0;
foreach($contents as $content)
     {
   echo $content;
   if($p_count == $show_after_p)
  {
?>
<aside class="thanks clearfix">
    <p>
      <?php echo '<span>Special thanks: </span>'.$thanks; ?>
    </p>
</aside>
<?php } 
echo "</p>";
$p_count++;
}
}
}
?>
```

**Why not JS?**
Well, javascript could definitely do this, but if I can do this in PHP then yahtzee.

Comment: 1) What have you tried already? 2) Show us your code 3) Show input data (where are you inserting data).

Comment: Wouldnt using javascript be more fitting to the task?  Also....a little code wouldnt hurt

Comment: I just added my present code. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: use regular expression and `preg_replace` - search for </p>{whitespaces (if any)}<p> and change whitespaces to your text

Comment: Use `DOMDocument` and it will be pretty much like JavaScript. But regex works well here too.

Answer (score 1):

use regular expression and `preg_replace` - search for: `(closing of P){whitespaces (if any)}(opening P)` and change whitespaces to your text.

something like that:

```
 $content = preg_replace('#</p>\s*<p#', "</p><aside> INSERT THIS HERE </aside><p", $content);
```

Comment: Sounds like an ultra simple solution! I'll give it a try and get back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to [Jerzy Zawadzki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351174/jerzy-zawadzki) for the inspiration. If you refer to the original code I segmented the content at the P tags using explode(). Now I am using preg_split() as follows:

```
$contents == preg_split('#</p>\s*<p>#', $content); // Thanks Jerzy
$i = 0;
foreach ( $contents as $content ) { 
  echo $content;
  if ( $i == $show_after_p ) { // this is set to 0 right now
    // insert aside here
  }
  echo "<p>";
  $i++;
 }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this busts up the content only at segments where there are concurrent paragraphs and no whitespace / images / other elements. At this first junction, I insert the aside. Then the content is appears as normal.